# How to include a static library inside another static library on IOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I have a static library let's call it ***third_party.a*** , I have integrated this in my ***util_library.a*** by adding it to **Link binary with library** option in **Build Phase** on Xocde. Now when I integrate util_library in my **testingApp** , it doesn't build as it cannot file the headers of **third_party** library . Is there a way where I don't have to include the headers of third_party in my testingApp and build it.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't build because of headers, its because you have included a header in a public header file.  You need to refactor your code so that the third party header file is only included in .cpp/.c files, or included in header files that aren't included by the user's application.